# What will be regular expression of domain URL of "www.google.com"?

Tags: c#, regex

What will be the regex for RegularExpressionValidator in asp.net for domain name like "www.google.com"?

**Valid Cases:**

1. www.google.com
2. www.youwebsite.com

**Invalid Cases:**

1. http://www.google.com
2. https://www.google.com
3. google.com
4. www.google

Currently I used `(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9]` but it fails for invalid case number 3 and 4.

Comment: Must it always be `www.` and `.com`, or may they be any subdomain and any tld?

Comment: What about `var isGoogle = new UriBuilder("google.com").Uri.Host.EndsWith("google.com")`? If you're looking for a more general case, have you considered domains like "google.co.uk" - would you be looking for "co.uk" here or "google.co.uk"?

Answer (score 1):

The pattern that you tried fails for the third and fourth of the invalid cases because in general you are matching `a-z0-9` and then repeat 1+ times `.` followed by `a-z0-9` which does not take a www into account.

If you want to keep your pattern, you should make sure that it starts with `www.`

```
^www\.(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9]$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ydB6jS/1)

You might shorten your pattern and make the match a bit broader:

```
^www\.[a-z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9-]+)*\.com$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cjjXcK/1)

You can always extend the character class if you want to allow matching more characters.

Answer (score 0):

This matches the part you want.

```
\bwww\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,256}\.com\b
```

[image]

But easier way to go with such a simple pattern is to use [StartsWith](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.startswith?view=netframework-4.8), [EndsWith](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.endswith?view=netframework-4.8), and then check what is in between.

Comment: OP don't want to match `http://www.google.com` i think you need to replace your first `\b` with `^ or \s`

Comment: @CodeManiac, it doesn't match against `http://www.google.com`. The parts highlighted in blue are the bits that it matches with, not the whole line.

Comment: @JakeMillington OP added this as invalid case in question, to me that means it should not match.

Comment: @CodeManiac. Again, it doesn't match against `http://www.google.com`. It's matching against the `www.google.com` part of the line `http://www.google.com`. This is valid. If that whole line was blue, then it would be in violation.

Comment: @CodeManiac. Anyway, they want to match a domain name. In both cases, the protocol is irrelevant. But also in both cases, there is a domain name.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that we would have valid ULRs as listed, we can start with a simple expression such as:

```
^www\..+\.com
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/QZkhQ2/1)

Then, we can add additional boundaries, if desired. For instance, we could add char class and end anchor, such as:

```
^www\..+\.com$
^www\.[A-Za-z_]+\.com$
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/TVmVCX/1)

If necessary, we would continue adding more constraints and test:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"^www\.[A-Za-z_]+\.com";
        string input = @"www.google.com
www.youwebsite.com

http://www.google.com
https://www.google.com
google.com
www.google";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]